# Unable to get jquery.jqgrid 4.4.1 working in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: jqgrid, asp.net-mvc-4

I have been struggling to get jquery.jqgrid 4.4.1 working in my ASP.NET MVC 4 solution.  I used NuGet to get jquery.jqgrid 4.4.1 installed into my project.  I am attempting to insert a very simple grid into my page, just to make sure that my includes are all setup correctly.  Here is what I have in my View file.

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<link href="~/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/jquery.jqGrid/ui.jqgrid.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css" rel="stylesheet" />

                <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/i18n/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>


<h2>Index</h2>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#myGrid").jqGrid({
        url:'@Url.Action("GetJqGridData")',
        datatype:'json',
        myType:'GET',
        colNames:['Id', 'Name'],
        colModel:[
        { name: 'Id', index: 'Id'},
        { name: 'Name', index: 'Name'}
        ],
        jsonReader: {
            root: 'Data',
        id: 'id',
        repeatitems: false
        },
        pager: $('#myPager'),
        rowNum:5,
        rowList: [2, 5, 10],
        width:600,
        viewrecords:true,
        caption: 'Jqgrid MVC Tutorial'
    });
});
</script>

    <table id="myGrid"></table>
    <div id="myPager"></div>
```

Here is the Javascript error that I am receiving when running the solution.

> Unhandled exception at line 54, column 5 in site/Grid
>
> 0x800a01b6 - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'jqGrid'

The View never even gets to the point of calling the controller for the data.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Updated**
Here is the HTML that is sent to the browser for additional detail.
    
    
        
            
            Index - My ASP.NET MVC Application

```
        <script src="/Scripts/modernizr-2.5.3.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <div class="content-wrapper">
                <div class="float-left">
                    <p class="site-title"><a href="/">your logo here</a></p>
                </div>
                <div class="float-right">
                    <section id="login">
                            <ul>
        <li><a href="/Account/Register" id="registerLink">Register</a></li>
        <li><a href="/Account/Login" id="loginLink">Log in</a></li>
    </ul>

                    </section>
                    <nav>
                        <ul id="menu">
                            <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/Home/About">About</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/Grid">Grid Test</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/Home/Contact">Contact</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
        <div id="body">

            <section class="content-wrapper main-content clear-fix">

<link href="/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/Content/jquery.jqGrid/ui.jqgrid.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/i18n/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


<h2>Index</h2>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#myGrid").jqGrid({
        url:'/Grid/GetJqGridData',
        datatype:'json',
        myType:'GET',
        colNames:['Id', 'Name'],
        colModel:[
        { name: 'Id', index: 'Id'},
        { name: 'Name', index: 'Name'}
        ],
        jsonReader: {
        root: 'Data',
        id: 'id',
        repeatitems: false
        },
        pager: $('#myPager'),
        rowNum:5,
        rowList: [2, 5, 10],
        width:600,
        viewrecords:true,
        caption: 'Jqgrid MVC Tutorial'
    });
});
</script>

<table id="myGrid"></table>
<div id="myPager"></div>
            </section>
        </div>
        <footer>
            <div class="content-wrapper">
                <div class="float-left">
                    <p>&copy; 2012 - My ASP.NET MVC Application</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </footer>

        <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>


    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried adding the type attribute, but that did not resolve the issue.  I have added the rendered HTML that is sent to the browser to the original post for added detail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fired up a new project and installed the grid via the nuGet package and it looks to me is that you are causing a conflict with the default resource bundler that is setup with MVC4 projects by default now. You will either need to remove the following line from the Views/Shared/_Layout file:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
```

Which will remove the bundled scripts.

Or add your jqGrid script references to the bundle config in the App_Start folder, and then remove the script tags from your view.

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                            "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js",
                            "~/Scripts/i18n/grid.locale-en.js",
                            "~/Scripts/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"));

<!----Remove These From your view-------!>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/i18n/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.  The bundles are what was causing the error.  I created a new bundle for the jqgrid scripts.  I also needed to move where the scripts were rendered.  They were originally put at the bottom of the layout, which was causing problems.  I moved them to the head and the issue was resolved.  Thanks for the help.