# Jqgrid not rendering and on Debugging it shows Undefined is not a function error

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

I am trying to add a JQgrid in my project, When i am trying to do a demo with the simple HTML page it shows the grid but when i added the same code to MVC application in a partial view the grid is not rendered. when i was debugging it shows the jqGrid() as undefined. 
Here is my Code ...

```
<html>
    <head>

   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.7/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/themes/ui.jqgrid.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
         <script type="text/javascript">
             $.jgrid.no_legacy_api = true;
             $.jgrid.useJSON = true;
    </script>
    <script src="http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#reportList").jqGrid(
    {
        url: '',
        datatype: "json",
        mtype: 'GET',
        colNames: ['Id', 'First Name', 'Last Name', 'Last 4 SSN', 'Department', 'Age', 'Salary', "Address", 'Marital Status'],
        colModel: [
        { name: 'EmloyeeId', index: 'EmloyeeId', width: 20, stype: 'text' },
        { name: 'FName', index: 'FName', width: 150 },
        { name: 'LName', index: 'LName', width: 150 }, { name: 'SSN4', index: 'SSN4', width: 100 },
        { name: 'Department', index: 'Department', width: 80, align: "right" },
        { name: 'Age', index: 'Age', width: 80, align: "right" },
        { name: 'Salary', index: 'Salary', width: 80, align: "right" },
        { name: 'Address', index: 'Address', width: 150, sortable: false },
        { name: 'MaritalStatus', index: 'MaritalStatus', width: 100, sortable: false }], rowNum: 10,
        sortname: 'EmloyeeId',
        viewrecords: true,
        sortorder: "desc",
        caption: "List Employee Details",
        scrollOffset: 0
    });
            });
            //jQuery("#reportList").jqGrid({
            //    dattatype: "json",
            //    colNames: ["Name", "Public", "DataMart", "Category", "Created By", "Created Time", "Status", "Default Format"],
            //    colModel: [
            //        { name: "ReportName", index: "ReportName", width: 50 },
            //        { name: "Public", index: "Public", width: 20 },
            //        { name: "Datamart", index: "Datamart", width: 50 },
            //        { name: "Category", index: "Category", width: 50 },
            //        { name: "CreatedBy", index: "CraetedBy", width: 50 },
            //        { name: "CreatedTime", index: "CreatedTime", width: 50 },
            //        { name: "Status", index: "status", width: 50 },
            //        { name :"DefaultFormat",index:"DefaultFormat",width:50}
            //    ],
            //    rowNum: 10,
            //    rowList: [10, 20, 30],
            //    multiSelect: true,
            //    recordPos: "left",
            //    sortName: "ReportName",
            //    viewRecords: true,
            //    caption: "Report List",
            //    pager:"#reportListPager"
            //});
            //$("#reportList").jqGrid("navGrid", "#reportListPager", { add: false, del: false, edit: false, position: 'right' });
        </script>
        <style type="text/css">
            .header{ height: 3em; width:inherit; }
            .profileinfo{ font-size: 20px;
font-family: 'Segoe UI';
font-weight: 600;
float:left;
vertical-align: -webkit-baseline-middle;
margin: .5em;
}
            .navbutton{  
height: 3em;
width: 6em;
margin-top: .5em;
margin-right: 1em; 
float:right;
            }

            .ReportgridPanel
            {
                 border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
                 height: 26em;
            }
            .searchButton{width: 100px; height: 30px; border-radius: 8px; float: right; margin-right: 70px; cursor:pointer; font-size:15px; font-family:'Segoe UI'; font-weight:500;}

            .searchcontrol
            {width: 23em;
margin-top: 1em;
float: right;
margin-right: 1em;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="ManinContent" style="border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;">
            <div id="Header" class="header">
                <label id="lb_ProfileInfo" class="profileinfo"> Welcome Admin...</label>
                <div class="navbutton">
                    <span>
                        <img src="~/Content/images/Datasource.png" title="Data Source" />
                    </span>
                    <span>
                       <img src="~/Content/images/list.png" title="Report Category" />
                    </span>
                    <span>
                        <img src="~/Content/images/security.png" title="Security" />
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="gridPanel" class="ReportgridPanel">
                <div style="width:inherit;">
                <div class="searchcontrol">
                    <input type="text" title="search"  />
                    <button title="Search" class="searchButton">Search</button>
                </div>
                    </div>
                <table id="reportList">
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Should `jqgrid/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js` be before `jqgrid/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js`?

Comment: I had tried that even the same error occurs.

Comment: Where does the error occur? (you should not be using `.min` versions when debugging)

Comment: while debugging i am using unminified version only. $("#reportList").jqGrid() function itself showing the error but works fine in simple html file ..

Comment: The code you have posted shows the `.min` versions and you mentioned a partial view (this code is not a partial view) therefore this is not the real code which makes it impossible to help

Comment: I had added the jquery.jqgrid.src.js file into my local <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.jqgrid.src.js></script> and the above code is added to the partial view of the ReportController.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69024/discussion-between-gowthaman-and-stephen-muecke).

Comment: Maybe you should move  
<script type="text/javascript">
             $.jgrid.no_legacy_api = true;
             $.jgrid.useJSON = true;
  </script> after referencing jquery.jqGrid.min.js

Comment: Thanks alex.  Tried that same error repeats..

Comment: "and the above code is added to the partial view of the ReportController." - do you have <head> section in your partial view?

Comment: is that the mistake..? will it work if i remove the <head> section.

Comment: Have the file `<!DOCTYPE html>` line before `<html>`? Is `url: ''` correct? Do you need to load JSON data from the same URL? What version of jqGrid you use? What is the line number in `jquery.jqgrid.src.js` where you get the error? You use **retro version 1.4.4 of jQuery** . Why? The current version of jqGrid support 1.7.2 or higher. I recommend you to use jQuery 1.11.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem. The issue was in Layout.cshtml partial view, which had

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

inside body. I moved it to the head of Layout.cshtml, and it worked, grid showed up.

Solution taken from [Unable to get jquery.jqgrid 4.4.1 working in ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14064492/unable-to-get-jquery-jqgrid-4-4-1-working-in-asp-net-mvc)

Answer (score 0):

I could think about 2 potential reasons for this issue:

1. Adding jQgrid script more than once. Since you wrote that all the code that you supplied is a part of partial view if you also have `<script src="http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` in your layout or other partial view thiscould cause such an error (I have experienced similar issues when by mistake added multiple references to jQuery script).
2. Wrong structure of your rendered html. If all this code is part of partial view and you render it inside some other view or layout you will have invalid html document since it will include multiple `html`, `head` and `body` tags. In general the only place that should contain those tags is a Layout view:

```html
<html>    
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8" />
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.7/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/themes/ui.jqgrid.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
      <div class="container body-content">
         @RenderBody()
      </div>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script src="http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
    </body>
</html>
```

If you are going to use jqgrid in multiple views you could add it's script to the layout (But you should be aware the the more scripts/content you add to the layout the slower your site will be. It is considered to be a good practice to render the minimal amount of scripts on initial page load improve site's performance). If you are adding jqgrid script to the _Layout.cshtml, your partial view should look something like like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#reportList").jqGrid(
    {
        url: '',
        datatype: "json",
        mtype: 'GET',
        colNames: ['Id', 'First Name', 'Last Name', 'Last 4 SSN', 'Department', 'Age', 'Salary', "Address", 'Marital Status'],
        colModel: [
        { name: 'EmloyeeId', index: 'EmloyeeId', width: 20, stype: 'text' },
        { name: 'FName', index: 'FName', width: 150 },
        { name: 'LName', index: 'LName', width: 150 }, { name: 'SSN4', index: 'SSN4', width: 100 },
        { name: 'Department', index: 'Department', width: 80, align: "right" },
        { name: 'Age', index: 'Age', width: 80, align: "right" },
        { name: 'Salary', index: 'Salary', width: 80, align: "right" },
        { name: 'Address', index: 'Address', width: 150, sortable: false },
        { name: 'MaritalStatus', index: 'MaritalStatus', width: 100, sortable: false }], rowNum: 10,
        sortname: 'EmloyeeId',
        viewrecords: true,
        sortorder: "desc",
        caption: "List Employee Details",
        scrollOffset: 0
    });
            })
</script>

<div id="ManinContent" style="border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;">
            <div id="Header" class="header">
                <label id="lb_ProfileInfo" class="profileinfo"> Welcome Admin...</label>
                <div class="navbutton">
                    <span>
                        <img src="~/Content/images/Datasource.png" title="Data Source" />
                    </span>
                    <span>
                       <img src="~/Content/images/list.png" title="Report Category" />
                    </span>
                    <span>
                        <img src="~/Content/images/security.png" title="Security" />
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="gridPanel" class="ReportgridPanel">
                <div style="width:inherit;">
                <div class="searchcontrol">
                    <input type="text" title="search"  />
                    <button title="Search" class="searchButton">Search</button>
                </div>
                    </div>
                <table id="reportList">
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
```